# Evaluation of ranking results in Information Retrieval

Tags: ranking, information-retrieval

How can we evaluate the ranking of results for an Information Retrieval system  in an Unsupervised scenario?

Comment: you mean when u don't have relevance assessments?

Comment: Yeah, when I don't have a ground truth to evaluate

Answer (score 1):

A way to estimate the quality of the retrieved information without the presence of relevance assessments is with the help of *Query Performance Prediction* (or QPP for short). There exists a considerable volume of work on QPP in the IR literature, which you can dig up from the SIGIR/CIKM conferences.

Broadly speaking, it uses the idea that a top-retrieved set of documents, if significantly different from the collection, is a reasonable indication that the top retrieved set is focussed on a specific topic, and hence likely to be relevant because essentially relevance is a property which is also supposed to be focused on a particular topic (this is just an assumption but this is the best we can do without assessments).

A simple technique to estimate the distinctive nature of the top-k documents then would be to check the skewness of these scores -- the more skewed they are, the higher is the likelihood of the top-k being different from the rest (and hence the retrieval being good).

The figure below (taken from this [TOIS paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2180868.2180873)) shows how standard deviation can be used as a measure of (inverse) skewness. The std_dev of the left distribution is less (the value is closer to the average), so this is an example of a query for which the system hasn't been able to retrieve useful documents.

[image]

In contrast to the standard usage of QPP which compares between two queries, in your case the query is fixed and you basically would compare across retrieval models (e.g. the score distribution with tf-idf could be less skewed than BM25).